# Python call class function as other classes attribute

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

Is it possible to create a construction like this, where a method `foo` of a class `A` is used to set the value of an attribute of another class `B`. Then this method should be called on an instance of `A` without calling `A.foo()` directly.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("Hello")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = A.foo
    
    def bar(self):
        obj = A()
        obj.self.func()
```

My use case is that in the `__init__()` method of `B` different functions of `A` can be chosen for set the value of the attribute `self.func` by an `if-else` statement; this because calling the method of class A directly it is not possible, since it is not clear which one will be chosen.

Comment: I think it should work, provided you replace `obj.self.func()` with `self.func(obj)`

Comment: coupling implementation of two classes like this is likely to be a bad idea

Comment: @Anentropic right, it would be better if `func` were accepted as an argument to the `B` constructor, and the instance was provided as an argument to `bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you could just pass the instance explicitly:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("Hallo")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = A.foo
    
    def bar(self):
        obj = A()
        self.func(obj)
```

Comment: What if `foo`would take function arguments like `def foo(self, arg):`? How would I pass them? Like `self.func(obj, arg)`?

Comment: @mavex857 Yes you can use `self.func(obj, arg)`. May be you have to modify the `bar()` method and add to it the argument `arg` as followed: `def bar(self, arg):`.

Comment: @mavex857 yes, at this point it isn't acting like a method. It is just a regular function. You just pass all the arguments to it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I have added the `if-else` construct inside the `__init__()` method because you mention this construct in the question:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("Hallo")

    def foo1(self):
        print("Hallo 1")

    def foo2(self):
        print("Hallo 2")

class B:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        if x == 1:
            self.func = A.foo1
        elif x == 2:
            self.func = A.foo2
        else:
            self.func = A.foo

    def bar(self):
        obj = A()
        self.func(obj)

B().bar()
B(1).bar()
B(2).bar()
B(3).bar()
```

The execution of the script produces the following output:

```
Hallo
Hallo 1
Hallo 2
Hallo
```

The output shows that the `bar()` method call a different method of the class A and the method chosen depends on the value of the argument passed to the `__init__()` method.

### The instance of A is not necessary

Furthermore the method `bar()` of the class `B` could be the following:

```
def bar(self):
    self.func(A)
```

This because you can use the **attribute reference** instead the **Class instantiation** to access the `foo()` method of the class `A`.

Comment: Just a style suggestion, but I'd do it with an optional parameter: `def __init__(self, x=0):` rather than testing `len(x)`.

Comment: I have tested your suggestion and it works perfectly. I have modified my answer following your suggestion.